# Run an activity in background

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, mms

I'm using an activity to get MMS attachment once a MMS is received. I have completed the MMS listener for this and it will call the activity, which will use `getContentResolver()` to grab the attachment. I want the activity to run in the background, without showing the empty UI to the user. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a service to make this happen. It is basically an activity without a view.  Check out the link below for more info.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: Do I place the activity as a service, or do I place it alongside with the listener, since the listener will call the activity?

Comment: You'll want to have it as a separate class that extends service.  You'll also have to do some stuff with your manifest.  Check out the link and the pages it links to for all the details.  They should help you a bunch.  It took me a bit to get my head wrapped around the concepts so you might have to read it more than once like I did.

Comment: if this worked there is a tick mark on the left hand side to accecpt this as an answer. this helps you to get proper responses in the future.